# Random forest feature importance interpretation

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, importance

How to interpret the feature importance from the random forest:

```
                        0     0.pval          1     1.pval MeanDecreaseAccuracy  MeanDecreaseAccuracy.pval MeanDecreaseGini MeanDecreaseGini.pval
V1         47.09833780 0.00990099 110.153825 0.00990099           103.409279                0.00990099       75.1881378            0.00990099
V2         15.64070597 0.14851485  63.477933 0.00990099            59.578000                0.00990099       39.0916068            1.00000000
V3         9.34881572 0.42574257  53.046130 0.00990099            50.666761                0.00990099       27.3256807            0.12871287
V4         1.00008468 0.74257426  36.354319 0.00990099            32.756121                0.00990099        9.8516100            0.02970297
V5         2.72412912 0.55445545  39.909433 0.00990099            32.267828                0.00990099       15.8067480            0.14851485
V6         8.83687247 0.13861386  30.836204 0.00990099            29.405169                0.00990099        8.4570255            1.00000000
V7         3.91886497 0.50495050  19.309765 0.00990099            17.954713                0.00990099        5.5962984            0.00990099
```

Why is the MeanDecreaseAccuracy is significant for all variables, despite the fact that some of them are terrible in predicting the 0 in the data (all but V1 is not significant for 0.pval)?  Given that V1 is the only variable that is significant in all four criteria, can I safely say that V1 is the only important feature in predicting the response variable?

Comment: Don't trust any of this without bootstrapping the entire process to get fair confidence intervals on the variable importance measures.  You'll often be shocked at how unstable these measures are.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to bootstrap the process?  I thought the random forest model, during its generation, has already done that for me.

Comment: I ran the above test for 100 times and averaged the results (or should I use meta-analysis)?  It shows that the pattern persists: V1 is still the only one with significant MDG, but every variables have significant MDA.  Meanwhile, despite the fact that V1 is the most important variable, dropping this column will result in an increase in the f-value accuracy of the model.  Odd.